# Zend vs Symfony learning time

Tags: zend-framework, symfony1

Is faster to learn Zend Framework or Symfony?
Which framework has more and clear documentation?

Comment: Symfony 1 or 2? (bearing in mind that Symfony 2 is probably the one to learn for the future, but it's only just on the verge of being released, so the documentation's still being written...)

Comment: I thing the best framework which is big enough and has better documentation. Maybe need to look for other language like Java or .NET?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think both frameworks take some time to learn properly but you can't beat Symfony's documentation.

Comment: Yes, especially if you read the (slightly outdated, but still very helpful) "Ultimate guide to symfony" ( http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/1_2/ ). I'd also say Zend sometimes feels more like a set of tools than a framework, and symfony has a more "rigid" structure with many automated tasks, which makes symfony perhaps less versatile, but harder to get lost in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation for both is clear enough. But somehow it seems to be, that ZF is simplier to learn because it constist of many loosely coupled classes. Symfony is more consistent to me and it's fundamental terms like "bundle" are a little bit more difficult to learn than those of ZF.

Comment: How about form documentation? I read ZF documentation can't find about all decorators. I found what decorators can get options but what options?

Comment: Well, are we talking about framework in general or about details? ;) Indeed, documentation on decorators is lacking options description. I think this will be fixed: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5867

Comment: About frame work. This is no page there i can find description about all View Helpers only in code :(

Comment: I understand, but I can assure you that Symfony manual also does not cover 100% of its code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning Symfony, and I think that the l-curve for it it's very hard for the first days (at least a week of full-immersion), especially if you haven't ever heard about ORM, decoration, layouts, templates and so on. I'have spent 1 hour a week since november,2010 and now I'm stuck...
Zend is probably a bit easier, but I'm not so sure, depends on your technical background.
Some collegues of me say ZF is valid like Symfony and it's easier to learn. The online documentation is incomplete (words of a ZF specialist), and you should buy a third-party book to focus learning.
Symfony has instead a good choice of free online books (I'm using "Practical Symfony").

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would say zend is harder to learn... not because it is complex but because it is way simple in design. As many will point out, its loosely coupled. It can be integreated to anything... any other framework. To make such a developement friendly framework, the simplicity level is overreached. And to do one small thing, like modifying some form design, you end up getting tangled in too many things and start banging your head in between decorator pattern, factory pattern, but still learn nothing related to the framework itself. But give time, it will start making sense eventually and when it does, you will be happy that you **took the decision to go with zend framework**